# Doubly linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm teaching myself C and I'm trying to learn the doubly linked list now. Following the book's tutorial, I have found some problems:

```
typedef struct _seg {
   int  bits[256];
   struct _seg *next, *prev;
} seg;
EXTERN seg *head;
EXTERN seg *last;
```

Based on codes like this, I know that to go through the linkedlist from head, I can do something like:

```
seg *p;
p = head;
for ( i = 0; i < k; i++)              
p = p->next;
```

However, how can I reversely go through the linkedlist from the last node(defined as last)?

Comment: Your loop should be `for (int i=0; i<k && p != NULL; i++) p = p->next;` because your list might have fewer than `k` elements

Comment: By the way, identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved (if I'm not mistaken), so you should rather use trailing underscores instead (_e.g_ `seg_` instead of `_seg`).

Comment: I have the habit of declaring a `struct seg_st`; then perhaps `typedef struct seg_st seg_t;`

Comment: It is perfectly valid syntax to write `typedef struct foo { [...] } foo;`, no need for underscores at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reason symmetrically, and code e.g.

```
seg *p = last;
for (int j=0; j < k && p != NULL; j++)
  p = p->prev;
```

I have added the test `p != NULL` to avoid an [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (when the list has fewer than `k` elements; on many systems you would get a [segmentation violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) crash if you omit the test in that case).

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debugging info when compiling (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -g`) and learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`).

BTW, [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) is a different language than C99 or [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) (but with some compatibilities) and offer language support (thru its standard library) for linked lists using [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Comment: Hi, to initialize the linkedlist, i have `   for (i = 0; i < NSegs; i++)
   {
      p = (  seg *) malloc(sizeof (seg));  // Make a new segment
      p->next = head;             // Add the next segment to the list
      head = p; 
   }` How can I tell the computer that this is a doubly linked list? Do I need to mention last here as well?

Comment: No such thing as "telling" the computer it's a doubly linked list. Just initialize next and prev properly and use them at your desire.